# php json_decode() not working on encoded JSON string. Decoded value is NULL

Tags: javascript, php

This JSON data has been subjected to 'JSON.stringify().replace()' ,then i'm trying to `json_decode()` in php in the backend. But it wont work.

here is the program:

```
    <?php 
        $a="{\\\"data\\\":{\\\"lab\\\":[\\\"a\\\",\\\"b\\\",\\\"c\\\",\\\"4\\\",\\\"5\\\",\\\"6\\\",\\\"7\\\",\\\"8\\\",\\\"9\\\",\\\"dd\\\"],\\\"stats\\\":{\\\"t1\\\":{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Tier Creation\\\",\\\"t_name\\\":\\\"dd\\\",\\\"t_desc\\\":\\\"dd\\\"},\\\"t_up\\\":{\\\"d_name\\\":\\\"T Up\\\",\\\"id\\\":4,\\\"up_t\\\":\\\"Li cases\\\",\\\"up_val\\\":[\\\"1\\\",\\\"2\\\",\\\"3\\\",\\\"4\\\",\\\"5\\\",\\\"6\\\",\\\"7\\\",\\\"8\\\",9],\\\"sm_temp\\\":[\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\"],\\\"ms_end_id\\\":[\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\"],\\\"short_check\\\":[\\\"0\\\",\\\"0\\\",\\\"0\\\",\\\"0\\\",\\\"0\\\",\\\"0\\\",\\\"0\\\",\\\"0\\\",\\\"0\\\"],\\\"e_sub\\\":[\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"test\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"sda\\\",\\\"\\\"],\\\"e_dy\\\":[\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"<p>&lt;title&gt;&lt;\\/title&gt;\\\\\\\\n&lt;center&gt;&lt;img src=\\\\\\\\&quot;clouds.jpg\\\\\\\\&quot;\\/&gt;&lt;\\/center&gt;\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\n&lt;hr\\/&gt;\\\\\\\\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\\\\\\\\&quot;http:\\/\\/somegreatsite.com\\\\\\\\&quot;&gt;LinkName&lt;\\/a&gt;isalinktoanotherniftysite&lt;\\/p&gt;\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\n&lt;h1&gt;ThisisaHeader&lt;\\/h1&gt;\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\n&lt;h2&gt;ThisisaMediumHeader&lt;\\/h2&gt;\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\n&lt;p&gt;Sendmemailat&lt;a href=\\\\\\\\&quot;mailto:support@yourcompany.com\\\\\\\\&quot;&gt;support@yourcompany.com&lt;\\/a&gt;.&lt;\\/p&gt;\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\n&lt;p&gt;Thisisanewparagraph!&lt;\\/p&gt;\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Thisisanewparagraph!&lt;\\/strong&gt;&lt;br\\/&gt;\\\\\\\\n&lt;strong&gt;&lt;em&gt;Thisisanewsentencewithoutaparagraphbreak,inbolditalics.&lt;\\/em&gt;&lt;\\/strong&gt;&lt;\\/p&gt;\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\n&lt;hr\\/&gt;\\\\n\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"<p>upgraded from {{initialname}} to {{name}} on&nbsp; {{s_date}}\\\\n\\\\n<p>\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n&quot;,&quot;\\\\n\\\\n<p style=\\\"margin-left: 40px;\\\\\\\">{{name}} reached from{{initial_name}}on expiry date {{expiry_date}} name is {{full_name}}, first&nbsp; {{first_name}} and last {{last_name}}\\\\n\\\\n<p>\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n&quot;,&quot;\\\\n\\\\n<p>{{name}} from {{initial_name}} expires on {{expiry_date}} {{full_name}} and first {{first_name}} and last name {{last_name}}\\\\n\\\\n<p>\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n\\\\n\\\\n<p>hi hello\\\\n\\\",\\\"\\\"],\\\"t_id\\\":[\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\"],\\\"acc_id\\\":[\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\",\\\"\\\"]},\\\"aton\\\":{\\\"dime\\\":\\\"Po lcon\\\",\\\"grp\\\":{\\\"PRO\\\":{\\\"name\\\":\\\"PRO\\\",\\\"id\\\":2,\\\"a_type\\\":\\\"In terms of gg\\\",\\\"all\\\":[\\\"10.0\\\",\\\"20.0\\\",\\\"20.0\\\",\\\"100\\\",\\\"100\\\",\\\"100\\\",\\\"110\\\",\\\"100\\\",\\\"100\\\",100]},\\\"DEFAULT\\\":{\\\"name\\\":\\\"DEFAULT_ALL\\\",\\\"id\\\":3,\\\"al_type\\\":\\\"rated - In terms of gg\\\",\\\"alloc_val\\\":[\\\"100\\\",\\\"100\\\",\\\"100\\\",\\\"100\\\",\\\"100\\\",\\\"100\\\",\\\"120\\\",\\\"100\\\",\\\"100\\\",100]}}},\\\"finalize\\\":{\\\"lay_nam\\\":\\\"Fin\\\"}},\\\"curr_sym\\\":\\\"\\\"},\\\"ash_age\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"log\\\":[]}";




        $b = array();
        $b=json_decode($a,"\0") or die("json decode unsuccessful\n");

        echo ($b==NULL);

        echo print_r($b,true);

?>
```

output:
json decode unsuccessful

Comment: Why is there so many slashes? Those aren't necessary

Comment: It's not working because you have a mess of escaped " and \ characters so it's not valid json

Comment: actually it didnt have two sets of escape slashes., in order to avoid any syntax errors in the html inside the json i encoded it again to ensure safe decoding. wrong html should not mess with json decoding, that was my objective

Answer (score 0):

$a doesn't contain valid JSON. Those slashes are completely wrong, all you need to escape are the " inside the HTML strings and surround the JSON with ' instead of " (so it's $a = '{.....}'; ).